# Redirect url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp, redirect

How can i redirect the url using htaccess. I just tried a lot but couldnt find any proper way.

> https://demo.com/test.php?value=345

to

> https://demo.com/test.php?convert=1&p=345

Comment: yes....but its not redirecting.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^value=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /test.php?convert=1&p=$1 [NC]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^test.php/?$ test.php?convert=1&p=$1  [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler approach:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^value=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /test.php?convert=1&p=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```